# Chain rule - Find $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} $ if $z=pq+qw$

Tags: calculus, chain-rule

> Find $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and  $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} $ if
>
> $z=pq+qw$
>
> $p=2x-y$, $q=x-2y$ and $w=-2x-2y$

Is $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ equals to:

$\frac{\partial z}{\partial p} \frac{\partial p}{\partial x}+ \frac{\partial z}{\partial q} \frac{\partial q}{\partial x}+
\frac{\partial z}{\partial q} \frac{\partial q}{\partial x}+ \frac{\partial z}{\partial w} \frac{\partial w}{\partial x}$

Or
$\frac{\partial z}{\partial p} \frac{\partial p}{\partial x}+ \frac{\partial z}{\partial q} \frac{\partial q}{\partial x}+
\frac{\partial z}{\partial w} \frac{\partial w}{\partial x}$

I can complete the solution, I need only the correct rule. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial p} \frac{\partial p}{\partial x}+ \frac{\partial z}{\partial q} \frac{\partial q}{\partial x}+
\frac{\partial z}{\partial w} \frac{\partial w}{\partial x}=$, then

$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=p+w$ and

$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=-3q-2p-2w$

Comment: Thank you so much, for $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ I think it is $-q-2(p+w)$, what do you think?

Comment: Thankful. no $\frac{\partial z}{\partial w}\frac{\partial w}{\partial y}=-2q$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial p} \frac{\partial p}{\partial x}+ \frac{\partial z}{\partial q} \frac{\partial q}{\partial x}+
\frac{\partial z}{\partial w} \frac{\partial w}{\partial x}$$

Comment: Thank you so much